# cant create an intent activity in my main activity

Tags: android, kotlin

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:srcCompat="@drawable/pp" android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_centerInParent="false" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="127dp" android:text="KAROLINE" android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="36sp" android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <ScrollView android:layout_width="282dp" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/textView" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="false" android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    >

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="65dp"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:id="@+id/etUsername" android:hint="Username"/>
            <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/etPassword" android:layout_marginTop="20dp" android:hint="Password"/>
            <Button
                    android:text="LOGIN"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/buLogin"
                    android:background="@color/light_salmon" android:layout_marginTop="20dp" android:onClick="buLogin"/>
            <TextView
                    android:text="Create account"
                    android:onClick="buCreateacct"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView5" android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is an xml file of a user interface, i working with kotlin the problem am having is that buLogin and buCreateacct arent creating in my main activity,and i need this activity to begin another activity because am working on an e-commerce application

Comment: What do you mean by are not creating in main activity?

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming** added in `build.gradle` because of `app:srcCompat`

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}
```

**Check** that your second or third `activity` are defined in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. For instance:

```xml
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity"></activity>
<activity android:name=".ThirdActivity"></activity>
```

**Then** `buCreateacct` and `buLogin` functions you should have an `intent` and a call to `StartActivity` method so as to start the second or third activity. For instance:

```
fun buLogin(){
    val loginIntent = Intent(this,SecondActivity::class.java)

    //function logic before starting the second activity. For instance intent extras

    startActivity(loginIntent)
}
```